# Convert array of fp16 data to float in python

Tags: python, struct, casting

I have an array of debug data that has a fixed length, but variable content. Basically it comes from C union code:

```
 union Foo{
        __fp16   half[];
        float    full[];
        int8_t   int8[];
        uint8_t  uint8[];
        int16_t  int16[];
        uint16_t uint16[];
        int32_t  int32[];
        uint32_t uint32[4];
}
```

So in python I parsed it in an array of Bytes using:

```
struct.Struct('16B').unpack_from(data);
```

The data looks like this:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 226, 196, 116, 0, 0, 0)
```

The data was in this case filled with "fp16". The other data types are easy to extract, but how to extract halfs?
How can I extract it to a normal python "float"?

I tried with this, but the 'e' is not supported by my version of Struct:

```
struct.Struct('8e').unpack_from(data)
```